# GoogleSheet to Sum until empty row AND Group By "Personal"

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

[image]

I want to SUM D with 3 conditions :

1. Sum D until next empty row.
2. Sum D WHERE F="Peronal".
3. Sum D WHERE the 1st row below empty row DAY,Month,Year(B) = DAY,Month,Year(H)

I try this code but fail :

```
=IF(DAY($B$6:$B$100)=DAY(H2),SUM(B6:INDEX(B6:D,MATCH(TRUE,(B6:B=H)*(F6:H="Personal"),0))),"")
```

Really appreciate if someone may help me with this. Thank you.

My excel file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/158pqwo83yw0dcv/productive%20Group.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 My excel file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/158pqwo83yw0dcv/productive%20Group.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(H5:H, 
 QUERY({TO_DATE(B6:B), C6:C-B6:B, F6:F},
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col3 = 'Personal'
  group by Col1
  label sum(Col2)''"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Really appreciate your help.